# Play 2.4 + i18n: Using a database instead of property files for internationalization

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework-2.4, playframework-2.5

What I did works fine (at least it looks look it does), but I am not convinced this is the best way to do it...
Basically, I wanted to have my i18n translations in a database instead of property files so users can easily edit those translations and a cache can serve them to the other users within a short period of time - I use an Akka Actor to read from the database and create a cache used by the messageApi (before I always needed to redeploy with the changes in the property files).

**Basically, is what I did totally the wrong way to do it?**

*TranslationActor.scala :*

```
class TranslationActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => {
      Logger.info("Starting to cache the translations")
      TranslationActor.tempCache = ListMap.empty
      var translations: ListMap[String, String] = ListMap.empty
      for (acceptedLanguage <- TranslationActor.acceptedLanguages) {
        val translationLanguageId: Long = TranslationLanguage.findByCode(acceptedLanguage).get.id
        val languageTranslations: Seq[Translation] = Translation.findAllByLanguageId(translationLanguageId)
        translations = new ListMap[String, String]
        for (languageTranslation <- languageTranslations) {
          val tag = EnglishTranslation.findById(languageTranslation.englishTranslationId).get.tag
          var returnedTranslation: String = languageTranslation.translation
          if (returnedTranslation.isEmpty) {
            returnedTranslation = tag
          }
          translations += tag -> new CacheValue(new Locale(acceptedLanguage), returnedTranslation).stringVar
        }
        TranslationActor.tempCache += acceptedLanguage -> translations
      }
      TranslationActor.cache = TranslationActor.tempCache
      Logger.info("Finished to cache the translations")
    }
  }
}

object TranslationActor {
  var acceptedLanguages: Seq[String] = Seq("fr", "en")
  var cache: ListMap[String, ListMap[String, String]] = ListMap.empty
  var tempCache: ListMap[String, ListMap[String, String]] = ListMap.empty
}

class CacheValue(locale: Locale, string: String) {
  val created: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
  var messageFormat: MessageFormat = null
  var localeVar: Locale = locale
  var stringVar: String = string

  def isOlderThan(period: Long): Boolean = {
    (System.currentTimeMillis - created) > (period * 1000)
  }

  def getMessageFormat: MessageFormat = {
    if (messageFormat == null) {
      if (stringVar != null) {
        messageFormat = new MessageFormat(stringVar, localeVar)
      } else {
        messageFormat = new MessageFormat("", localeVar)
      }
    }
    messageFormat
  }
}
```

*ManageTranslationDaemon.scala :*

```
@Singleton
class ManageTranslationDaemon @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem, applicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {
  Logger.info("Scheduling the translation daemon")
  val translationActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new TranslationActor()))
  actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(1 seconds, 30 minutes, translationActor, "translationDaemon")

  applicationLifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    Logger.info("Shutting down translation daemon")
    Future.successful(actorSystem.shutdown())
  }
}
```

*TranslationGuiceConfiguration.scala :* (from an com.google.inject.AbstractModule)

```
class TranslationGuiceConfiguration extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() : Unit = {
    bind(classOf[ManageTranslationDaemon]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Then I extended parts of the DefaultMessagesApi (by looking at the code of MessagesApi) in
*MessagesPersoApi.scala :*

```
class MessagesPersoApi @Inject() (environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration, langs: Langs) extends DefaultMessagesApi(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration, langs: Langs) {

  private def joinPaths(first: Option[String], second: String) = first match {
    case Some(parent) => new java.io.File(parent, second).getPath
    case None => second
  }

  override protected def loadMessages(langCode: String): Map[String, String] = {
    TranslationActor.cache.getOrElse(langCode, loadMessagesFromFile("messages." + langCode))
  }

  protected def loadMessagesFromFile(langCode: String): Map[String, String] = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    environment.classLoader.getResources(joinPaths(messagesPrefix, langCode)).asScala.toList
      .filterNot(url => Resources.isDirectory(environment.classLoader, url)).reverse
      .map { messageFile =>
        Messages.parse(Messages.UrlMessageSource(messageFile), messageFile.toString).fold(e => throw e, identity)
      }.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String]) {_ ++ _}
  }

  override protected def loadAllMessages: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = {
    langs.availables.map(_.code).map { lang =>
      (lang, loadMessages(lang))
    }.toMap
      .+("default" -> loadMessagesFromFile("messages"))
      .+("default.play" -> loadMessagesFromFile("messages.default"))
  }
}
```

And finally created a module (play.api.inject.Module)
*MessagesPersoModule.scala :*

```
class MessagesPersoModule extends Module {
  def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) = {
    Seq(
      bind[Langs].to[DefaultLangs],
      bind[MessagesApi].to[MessagesPersoApi]
    )
  }
}
```

And at the end, used it in my *application.conf :*

```
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.i18n.I18nModule"
play.modules.enabled += "modules.MessagesPersoModule"
play.modules.enabled += "modules.TranslationGuiceConfiguration"
```

Does that actually make sense? It seemed to me that it was a bit "complicated" to write. Is there an easier way to do that same logic with less code/classes ?

Thanks,

Yoann

Comment: So, what are your observations after using it?

Comment: It works, and I still use it. But I am still unsure it is the right way to do it. The one thing you need to be aware of (and by you, I mean anybody that might update the database) is that the code would only serve you the new translations in 0 to 30min (max) because of how my Actor is started.

Comment: Hi, I am struggling with similar issue. Did you improve your system? Would you be so kind to post the full sources of MessagesPersoModule module somewhere? Would be super helpful.

Comment: The code of MessagesPersoModule is actually the full code I use, apart from the imports and package info. As I said in the previous comment, I am content with how it works for now and am still using it as it is written here. If my requirements change I might review and rewrite that code, but not planning on it for now.

Comment: Thank you. Your code actually helped me much. With your hint  I did my module, but with different, singleton approach. I don't use akka but I dispatch my method (loadCustomizedMessages which calls my service to get the messages from db) on extended DefaultMessageApi to fetch the db and trigger it on application start or on messages update.